# jdbcTemplate query prepared statement with multiple parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, prepared-statement, jdbctemplate

I am building my `sql` string like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM horse WHERE 1=1 ";
if (horse.getName() != null) {
    sql += "AND UPPER(name) LIKE ? ";
}
if (horse.getDescription() != null) {
    sql += "AND UPPER(description) LIKE ? ";
}
if (horse.getRating() != null) {
   sql += "AND rating=? ";
}
```

I want to find a match for entity depending on which parameters are passed. So if only `name` and `rating` are passed I would get something like: `SELECT * FROM horse WHERE 1=1 AND UPPER(name) LIKE ? AND rating=?`

Now I pass the `sql` string to query like this:

```
List<Horse> matchingHorses = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{horse.getName()}, mapHorse());
```

This returns a correct result but I have to pass to `new Object[] {}` only the parameters that I know that user is gonna pass or else I do not get anything. For example if user passes something like this:

```
{
  "description":"desc"
}
```

I won't get any results even if there is a `description` with "desc". If I do this:

```
List<Horse> matchingHorses = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{horse.getName(), horse.getDescription(), horse.getRating()}, mapHorse());
```

and pass only name I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM horse WHERE 1=1 AND UPPER(name) LIKE ? ];
Invalid value "2" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Invalid value "2" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-200]
```

Here is my `mapHorse()` row mapper:

```
private RowMapper<Horse> mapHorse() {
        return (resultSet, i) -> {
            Long horseId = resultSet.getLong("id");
            String horseName = resultSet.getString("name");
            String horseDesc = resultSet.getString("description");
            int horseRating = resultSet.getInt("rating");
            return new Horse(
                horseId,
                horseName,
                horseDesc,
                horseRating,
            );
        };
}
```

How do I implement this correctly?

Comment: If your SQL has *n* parameters (`?`), your `Object[]` must have *n* items. Build the `Object[]` as you define the SQL. Create an `ArrayList<Object>` and, each time you add a `?` to your SQL, add the value to that list. Then convert the list to `Object[]`.

Comment: @SJuan76 This works! Should I answer my question, or are you planing on posting an answer?

Comment: You may self-answer if you like.

Comment: @VinayHegde If I recall correctly, I couldn't get it to work like that. But the comment above that suggested to add  values to list and convert that list to `Object[]` did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
if (horse.getName() != null) {
    sql += "AND UPPER(name) LIKE :name ";
    params.addValue("name", horse.getName());
}
if (horse.getDescription() != null) {
    sql += "AND UPPER(description) LIKE :description ";
    params.addValue("description", horse.getDescription());
}
if (horse.getRating() != null) {
    sql += "AND rating=:rating ";
    params.addValue("rating ", horse.getRating());
}
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, mapHorse());
```

suggestion- better if you you use string builder.